# Installing Ubuntu on Macintosh PowerPC, no CD-drive, USB boot not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, macosx, powerpc

I've got a Macintosh PowerPC G5 running on Mac OSX 10.4, it's a bit too old to upgrade to 10.5 and 10.4 doesn't have compatibility with much.

I decided to install Ubuntu instead, I have attempted to make a bootable USB install however it didn't boot through the USB and I wasn't able to access the boot priority because it required a password (this is a hand-me-down I decided to try and fix up).

I also burned a bootable CD installer however it turns out the CD-Drive on the PowerPC seems to have died off.

Is there any other method to get Ubuntu onto this Mac OS X 10.4 PowerPC? I tried installing rEFIt as was mentioned in other posts but apparently it's not compatible either.

Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Elías

Comment: Try if you can get rid of the password by resetting the PRAM: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Answer (score 2):

I just did this with an iBook G4 (PowerPC CPU) and did a whole blog post about it! You *can* install Ubuntu via USB, but it requires some tricky hackery. You can read the whole post [here](https://sudodblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/how-to-install-ubuntu-mate-remix-on-a-powerpc-computer/), but I'll provide the basic steps in this answer.

---

1. Download the correct ISO & make a bootable USB stick however you want.
2. Stick the USB stick in the Mac & start the Mac up *while* holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. This will boot the Mac into [Open Firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware). Once you see the screen go white with some text on it, you can release those keys.
3. Type `boot ud:,\\:tbxi` and the Mac *should* start booting from the USB.

From there, it's relatively smooth sailing, depending on your hardware. If you have any issues, comment on my answer and I'll do my best to help you!

If you're the more DIY person and want to figure out solutions on your own, read the [PowerPCKnownIssues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues) wiki page - it's a great help.

Comment: Very cool! I did as you suggested, the only problem was it just booted up normally. So no booting from USB yet. I'm at least happy to see some reaction from the computer.

I'm fairly sure I typed it in correctly, is there be anything else I can do?

Comment: @EliasAndrason Yeah. Shut down & boot into Open Firmware again. This time, type in `dev usb0`, and then enter `ls`. If you see something like `/disk@1` returned from the `ls` command, comment back here.

Comment: Ran into another snag. After "dev usb0" I'm asked to enter the password. I appreciate your quick replies! Anything I can do now?

Also, I noticed you said "boot ud:,\\:tbxi" on your blog, and a slightly different version here. Is that significant?

Comment: @EliasAndrason I'm sorry, it should be `boot ud:,\\:tbxi`, I mis-typed. Try that (with two back-slashes.) Open Firmware commands are so cryptic :D

Comment: Tried twice with the corrected code, same deal. It flashes a screen with text but only for a fraction of a second so I can't make out the message.

Comment: @EliasAndrason Strange. Have to tried resetting the PRAM as suggested by Donarsson? If you can do that we might have more success with the USB boot.

Comment: I attempted that, oddly nothing seemed to happen. It works when I do Mac + Alt + F + O, but not Mac + Alt + P + R.

I discovered from Reddit that apparently I should be using the OS that you mentioned on your blog, Ubuntu MATE. I was using a regular ubuntu installer, would that affect anything?

Comment: @EliasAndrason Yeah, if resetting the PRAM didn't do anything. I can't think of any reason *why* it would affect anything, but we've exhausted everything else. Question: That password you keep mentioning, is it a BIOS password, or the password for a user on the machine? [Link to the MATE ISO](https://plus.google.com/111285327879595317710/posts/2dTTB6qBHrA).

Comment: Re-attempted this with a new flash drive and the compatible linux boot install. No luck. I did however manage to get a snapshot of the screen that blinks a moment before booting up as normal

http://imgur.com/D6rub52

What do you make of that? 

I even used a different keyboard incase the P and R keys weren't working. I don't know what's the problem!

Comment: @EliasAndrason Whoa, that's some Assembly language code loading there. Unfortunately, I don't know anything beyond that for what's on the screen. What happens after that happens again? Also, that password you keep mentioning, is it a BIOS password, or the password for a user on the machine?

Comment: After that I just return to the grey screen and boot normally. I'd say it's the BIOS password, as that's the only time I've encountered it. There is no password required for the user account.

Comment: Okay. that makes sense. Is there a battery anywhere on the motherboard you can remove and then put back in again? That might clear the password.

Comment: No dice. However, as I was removing the battery I noticed my CD-drive wasn't properly plugged into the motherboard. Now I'm downloading Ubuntu MATE and will give the bootable CD another shot. Will update on the result!

Comment: @EliasAndrason Sweet, not having something plugged in correctly does usually improve the odds of the thing not working :)

Comment: Indeed! Didn't improve enough, all I can do now is successfully eject and insert a CD, the computer doesn't seem to actually notice anything IN the drive. Found this out when I was trying to burn the boot CD on it. Is there a chance that it would successfully boot up even though it doesn't detect it when logged in? I mean... it does at least open and close! Hopefully I can get my hands on another computer with a burner and make it for it and try.

Comment: Well, do you have an external USB DVD drive? I've heard that these devices often can't read dual-layer DVDs, the kind that LiveCDs are (if I remember correctly...). Can you press & hold the `C` key while booting? That might let you boot the CD.

Comment: Holding C had no effect. As there is no available external CD-drive is there anything else I can do? This may be ridiculous but is it possible to put the HDD from the G5 into my working PC and install it from the desktop and return the HDD to the G5?

Comment: Update, I now have the password. Dev USB0 didn't get anything from the ls. Any new options arise when the password is known?

Comment: @EliasAndrason Try using a USB stick and press/holding `option` during boot (unless you've already tried that.) If you've got the password, you may be able to change the boot order now? Also, you mentioned earlier that the `boot ud` command required the password. If holding Option doesn't work, try going through Open Firmware again and entering the password when prompted.

Comment: Holding Alt/Option during boot brings me to the Macintosh HD, then after a short wait it shows me the ubuntu external flash drive! However, after selecting that I get to a black screen with a slight text marker on the top left corner, and all it is doing is getting progressively louder. Nothing else seems to be happening. As for the boot UD that didn't require a password as I recall, it simply flashed a screen then booted normally.

Comment: Okay, well, we're making head-way! When you say it's getting progressively louder - you mean the fans/HDD, right?

Comment: Yes sir, something along those lines! I eventually just shut it off. I'll take another crack at it in the morning, 3 AM here! When this is all good and solved I'm going to feel pretty damn satisfied.

Comment: That's fine! It's midnight as I answer this ... soooo. Strange that neither Open Firmware, nor the normal boot-up thingy on the Mac is working. One thing you could try is disconnecting the hard drive before you boot up the PC, then trying all three things I've mentioned (Option, C, & Open Firmware).

Comment: @EliasAndrason Anything new happen?

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party!  @RPi Awesomeness I ran my usb through Etcher with the usb stick being preformated to master boot - msdos(fat) as you stated in the tutorial.  After I attempt to run it on my power pc after entering boot ud:,\\:tbxi in open firmware terminal it starts to boot then the screen has a circle with a line through it.  Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

On Openfirmware type `dev / ls` and take note of the path to usb disk. Then create an alias for it with `devalias ud /ht@0,f2000000/pci@2/usb@b/disk@2` (use your path). Then boot as before.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when booting from a usb on an old PowerPC Mac, using a 3rd party tool or something included in your OS does not work. (This only works on macOS or Linux as far as I know. Maybe with another Unix based OS with a terminal(I'm not sure.)) Comment on my response to tell me if I put something wrong in the Linux section (my understanding of linux is not as good as macOS)

### USING MACOS

1. Once you've downloaded your iso file and have plugged your USB stick into your computer open up a terminal.
2. Type `diskutil list` it should show a list of drives and their partitions. Find your USB drive.
3. Next, type `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` where /dev/disk2 is changed so it matches up with your USB stick. Note: if this command comes back with unmount failed use `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` It may ask for your password.
4. Next, type `cd` to go into wherever you have your .iso saved. If you saved it to your downloads all you should have to do is type `cd /Downloads`.
5. Finally, type `dd if=YOURISONAMEHERE.iso of=/dev/disk2` Make sure you use the device from step 3. IF this fails with permission denied you can type `sudo dd if=YOURISONAMEHERE.iso of=/dev/disk2`. Again use the device from step 3. You may be prompted for a passoword. This may take a while depending on the size of your USB stick.

6.Remove the USB stick from your machine and plug it into the PowerPC Mac. Turn on the Mac and hold COMMAND+OPTION+O+F

7.Then type `boot ud:,\\:tbxi`.

### USING LINUX

1. Once you've downloaded your iso file and have plugged your USB stick into your computer open up a terminal.
2. Type `sudo fdisk -l` it should show a list of drives and their partitions. Find your USB drive.
3. Next, type `sudo umount /dev/sdX` where X is changed so it matches up with your USB stick. It may ask for your password.
4. Next, type `cd` to go into wherever you have your .iso saved. If you saved it to your downloads all you should have to do is type `cd /home/yourusernamehere/Downloads`.
5. Finally, type `sudo dd if=YOURISONAMEHERE.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync` Make sure you use the device to replace the X from step 3. You may be prompted for a passoword. This may take a while.

6.Remove the USB stick from your machine and plug it into the PowerPC Mac. Turn on the Mac and hold COMMAND+OPTION+O+F

7.Then type `boot ud:,\\:tbxi`.